# PIP install AIMRocks fails on Windows

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to `pip install aim` which requires aimrocks, and this fails...

```
Collecting cython==3.0.0a9
Downloading Cython-3.0.0a9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aimrocks==0.2.1 (from versions: 0.2.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for aimrocks==0.2.1
```

For a work around I can use WSL, but it would be nice if I can just use Windows.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This bug was reported on github a month ago, and no meaningful reply was given.

https://github.com/aimhubio/aim/issues/2064